# Enable and set focus to text input field with checkbox in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox

I have a Bootstrap 3 prepended text field with a checkbox.  I want the field to be disabled until the checkbox is true, and then I want to not only enable it but set focus to it

I used the following code and the enable/disable works great, but not sure how to set the focus...

I will likely write a directive, but I was wondering if there was some very simple way to do it as there was for the disable/enable

```
<div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon">
        <input type="checkbox" name="cbprepend" ng-model="cbprepend">
    </span>
    <input type="text" id="cbprependfield" class="form-control" ng-disabled="!cbprepend">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your approach using a directive is good, but lacks some "angularity".

Here is another possible solution. First, create the directive:

```
.directive('checkableInput', function() {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'your/template/dir/checkable-input.html',
    scope: {
        id: "@",
        model: "="
    },
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        var input = element.find('#' + scope.id);
        scope.toggleFocus = function() {
            if(scope.model) {
                input.focus();
            } else {
                input.blur();
            }
        }
    }
  };
});
```

The template specified in `templateUrl` looks like this:

```
<div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon" >
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="model" ng-change="toggleFocus()">
    </span>
    <input type="text" ng-id="id" class="form-control" ng-enabled="model">
</div>
```

This is how you use it:

```
<checkable-input id="cbprependfield" model="cbprepend" />
```

Comment: This doesn't work throws an error: SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'link'. Expected '}' to end a object literal.

Comment: Found a missing comma before "link".  Except the toggling of the text file does not occur...  The template shows, I can check the checkbox but nothing on the field.  No console errors.

Comment: the issue might be here, or at least i don't understand this part: `var input = element.find('#' + scope.id);`  since `scope.id` logs as `cbprependfield`.  which is to in the template...

Comment: fixed the missing comma and removed obsolete `pcb`. do you need an id at all?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I did use a Directive, not sure if this is the cleanest way, please give me some criticism...

```
.directive('pcb', function() {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
        element.on({
            change: function(e) {
                if (element.is(':checked')) {
                    element.closest('.input-group').find('.focus-target').removeAttr('disabled')
                    element.closest('.input-group').find('.focus-target').focus();
                } else {
                    element.closest('.input-group').find('.focus-target').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                    element.closest('.input-group').find('.focus-target').blur();
                }
            }
        });
    }
  };
});
```

with the html

```
<div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon" >
                        <input type="checkbox" pcb ng-model="cbprepend">
                    </span>
                    <input type="text" id="cbprependfield" class="form-control focus-target" disabled>
                </div>
```

Comment: Using a directive is a good approach. But using dom traversing/manipulation is the wrong way. Instead, your directive should contain a template with your html which uses scope variables to  toggle attributes/classes etc.

Comment: Can you please point me to a link showing this approach?  I'm a jQuery dev (as if you couldn't tell) new to Angular and haven't come across templates yet.  Whoops just saw your reply.  Thanks.